# Recursive Tree Walk with ES6 Promise

Tags: javascript, recursion, binary-tree, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I'm looking to walk an object tree of unknown depth and return a given node via an ES6 promise. (used lodash here, obviously not necessary, I realize).  I've got the tree walking working fine but I'm a bit unclear the proper method to ensure that the top-level scope variable `promise` is passed into the recursive function calls so that it's available when calling `.resolve( data )`.  Right now it attempts to execute on a successful find but fails to resolve the promise since the recursive function has overwritten with a new promise and it fails to bubble up the chain:

```
  deepFindReturn (object, searchKey, searchVal, cb) {
    if ( !cb ) cb = _.noop;
    for(let x in object){
      if (object.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        if ( object[searchKey] === searchVal ) {
          return cb( object );
        }
        if ( _.isArray( object[x] ) && !this.found ){
          object[x].forEach( (item) => {
            this.deepFindReturn(item, searchKey, searchVal, cb);
          });
        } else if ( typeof object[x] === typeof {}  && !this.found ) {
          this.deepFindReturn(object[x], searchKey, searchVal, cb);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  deepFindReturn(data, 'uuid', 'f8d1ffed-9b51-4982-97b7-60f8e074eda4')
```

here's the tree I'm walking, in case it helps:

```
  data = {
     "name":"root",
     "created":"2015-04-07T20:36:29.711Z",
     "createdBy":"admin",
     "uuid":"9731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1",
     "primaryType":"folder",
     "path":"/root",
     "itemCount":7,
     "items":[
        {
           "name":"219760_964977275754_1803638_o.jpg",
           "baseVersion":"afe1994e-d9a8-47fd-a7db-dcf0e085fc05",
           "created":"2015-06-01T13:30:16.490Z",
           "lastModified":"2015-06-01T13:30:16.490Z",
           "isCheckedOut":true,
           "createdBy":"admin",
           "versionHistory":"152eb76a-e0ac-446d-a7e8-47b5e5c821ed",
           "primaryType":"file",
           "lastModifiedBy":"admin",
           "uuid":"25cc6435-6432-47f3-8dc3-f94f2788f2ef",
           "parent":"9731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1",
           "mimeType":"image/jpeg",
           "size":116285
        },
        {
           "name":"Child1",
           "created":"2015-04-07T21:03:41.729Z",
           "createdBy":"admin",
           "primaryType":"folder",
           "uuid":"f8d1ffed-9b51-4982-97b7-60f8e074eda4",
           "parent":"9731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1",
           "itemCount":36
        },
        {
           "name":"Child2",
           "created":"2015-04-07T21:14:47.950Z",
           "createdBy":"admin",
           "uuid":"8f1246ff-5053-411a-88de-c465027b998d",
           "primaryType":"folder",
           "parent":"9731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1",
           "itemCount":3
        },
        {
           "name":"Child3",
           "created":"2015-05-01T00:46:36.973Z",
           "createdBy":"admin",
           "uuid":"54f897a4-ac16-4585-83cb-d0e67ca73a74",
           "primaryType":"folder",
           "parent":"9731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1",
           "itemCount":1
        },
        {
           "name":"Child4",
           "created":"2015-05-26T18:18:33.159Z",
           "createdBy":"admin",
           "primaryType":"folder",
           "uuid":"ad1344a9-08b7-44bb-b47d-0efb99c59ac3",
           "parent":"9731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1",
           "itemCount":0
        },
        {
           "name":"Child5",
           "created":"2015-06-07T03:57:20.494Z",
           "createdBy":"admin",
           "primaryType":"folder",
           "uuid":"2b46d7e4-b50e-4eec-b97a-c46b2016926c",
           "parent":"9731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1",
           "itemCount":0
        },
        {
           "name":"content.jpg",
           "baseVersion":"620c8448-3e51-4a27-b630-60c1272c19da",
           "created":"2015-06-03T15:09:25.192Z",
           "lastModified":"2015-06-03T15:09:25.193Z",
           "isCheckedOut":true,
           "createdBy":"admin",
           "versionHistory":"871afa2a-5a2c-4762-bc26-a69022234850",
           "primaryType":"file",
           "lastModifiedBy":"admin",
           "uuid":"c8c63420-b525-4b36-bce3-a7c4cc55c07a",
           "parent":"9731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1",
           "mimeType":"image/jpeg",
           "size":30711
        }
     ]
  }
```

Comment: a) a promise cannot be `.resolve()`d from outside b) WTH are you using promises here when you're doing nothing asynchronous?!

Comment: more of an exercise in understanding than anything else, I already have this working without promises.  I get your point, there is no way to do this with promises so it's a futile experiment.

Comment: Can you show the promise-less version please?

Comment: You just remove the line `const promise = Promise.resolve()` and replace the line `promise.resolve( object )` with `return object`.  Pretty straightforward.

Comment: Uh, that doesn't look like "working", because that would require a `return` for the recursive calls as well ("fails to bubble up the chain" in your terms). Or is the entire purpose of this function to set the `this.found` property to `true`?

Comment: Indeed you're right.  I'll get it working and then update.

Comment: Ah, a callback. Do you expect possibly multiple matches?

Comment: Not in this case, my use case is a lookup by UUID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd move the bulk of the logic into another function and wrap that function in a `Promise`. I'm not sure the is any benefit to recursively creating promises for each branch of the tree. The function is non-blocking, with only minimal changes to logic.

```
function deepFindReturn (object, searchKey, searchVal) {
  function doer(object, searchKey, searchVal) {
    if ( object[searchKey] === searchVal ) {
      return object;
    }

    for(let x in object) {
      let val = object[x];

      if (typeof val === typeof searchVal) {
        continue;
      }

      if ( Array.isArray( val ) ) {
        for (let item of val) {
          let o = doer(item, searchKey, searchVal);
          if (o) {
            return o;
          }
        }
      }
      else if ( typeof val === 'object' ) {
        let o = doer(val, searchKey, searchVal);
        if (o) {
          return o;
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    resolve(doer(object, searchKey, searchVal));
  });
}

deepFindReturn(data, 'uuid', 'f8d1ffed-9b51-4982-97b7-60f8e074eda4')
  .then((o) => { console.log(o); });
```

[Live Demo](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=true&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=%20let%20data%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%22root%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%22created%22%3A%222015-04-07T20%3A36%3A29.711Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%22createdBy%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%22uuid%22%3A%229731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%22primaryType%22%3A%22folder%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%22path%22%3A%22%2Froot%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%22itemCount%22%3A7%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%22items%22%3A%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%22219760_964977275754_1803638_o.jpg%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22baseVersion%22%3A%22afe1994e-d9a8-47fd-a7db-dcf0e085fc05%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22created%22%3A%222015-06-01T13%3A30%3A16.490Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22lastModified%22%3A%222015-06-01T13%3A30%3A16.490Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22isCheckedOut%22%3Atrue%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22createdBy%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22versionHistory%22%3A%22152eb76a-e0ac-446d-a7e8-47b5e5c821ed%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22primaryType%22%3A%22file%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22lastModifiedBy%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22uuid%22%3A%2225cc6435-6432-47f3-8dc3-f94f2788f2ef%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22parent%22%3A%229731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22mimeType%22%3A%22image%2Fjpeg%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22size%22%3A116285%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%22Child2%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22created%22%3A%222015-04-07T21%3A14%3A47.950Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22createdBy%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22duuid%22%3A%22f8d1ffed-9b51-4982-97b7-60f8e074eda4%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22uuid%22%3A%228f1246ff-5053-411a-88de-c465027b998d%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22primaryType%22%3A%22folder%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22parent%22%3A%229731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22itemCount%22%3A3%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20children%3A%20%5B%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%22Child1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22created%22%3A%222015-04-07T21%3A03%3A41.729Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22createdBy%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22primaryType%22%3A%22folder%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22uuid%22%3A%22f8d1ffed-9b51-4982-97b7-60f8e074eda4%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22parent%22%3A%229731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22itemCount%22%3A36%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%22Child3%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22created%22%3A%222015-05-01T00%3A46%3A36.973Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22createdBy%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22uuid%22%3A%2254f897a4-ac16-4585-83cb-d0e67ca73a74%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22primaryType%22%3A%22folder%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22parent%22%3A%229731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22itemCount%22%3A1%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%22Child4%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22created%22%3A%222015-05-26T18%3A18%3A33.159Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22createdBy%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22primaryType%22%3A%22folder%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22uuid%22%3A%22ad1344a9-08b7-44bb-b47d-0efb99c59ac3%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22parent%22%3A%229731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22itemCount%22%3A0%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%22Child5%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22created%22%3A%222015-06-07T03%3A57%3A20.494Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22createdBy%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22primaryType%22%3A%22folder%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22uuid%22%3A%222b46d7e4-b50e-4eec-b97a-c46b2016926c%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22parent%22%3A%229731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22itemCount%22%3A0%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%22content.jpg%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22baseVersion%22%3A%22620c8448-3e51-4a27-b630-60c1272c19da%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22created%22%3A%222015-06-03T15%3A09%3A25.192Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22lastModified%22%3A%222015-06-03T15%3A09%3A25.193Z%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22isCheckedOut%22%3Atrue%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22createdBy%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22versionHistory%22%3A%22871afa2a-5a2c-4762-bc26-a69022234850%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22primaryType%22%3A%22file%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22lastModifiedBy%22%3A%22admin%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22uuid%22%3A%22c8c63420-b525-4b36-bce3-a7c4cc55c07a%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22parent%22%3A%229731cedc-8ed7-4367-b95d-30898c7913a1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22mimeType%22%3A%22image%2Fjpeg%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22size%22%3A30711%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%5D%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%0Afunction%20deepFindReturn%20(object%2C%20searchKey%2C%20searchVal)%20%7B%0A%20%20function%20doer(object%2C%20searchKey%2C%20searchVal)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(%20object%5BsearchKey%5D%20%3D%3D%3D%20searchVal%20)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20object%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20for(let%20x%20in%20object)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20val%20%3D%20object%5Bx%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(typeof%20val%20%3D%3D%3D%20typeof%20searchVal)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20continue%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(%20Array.isArray(%20val%20)%20)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20item%20of%20val)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20o%20%3D%20doer(item%2C%20searchKey%2C%20searchVal)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(o)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20o%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20if%20(%20typeof%20val%20%3D%3D%3D%20'object'%20)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20o%20%3D%20doer(val%2C%20searchKey%2C%20searchVal)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(o)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20o%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20return%20new%20Promise(function(resolve)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20resolve(doer(object%2C%20searchKey%2C%20searchVal))%3B%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AdeepFindReturn(data%2C%20'uuid'%2C%20'f8d1ffed-9b51-4982-97b7-60f8e074eda4')%0A%20%20.then((o)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(o)%3B%20%7D)%3B)

If however, the point of the exercise was to experiment with recursive asynchronous code, I'd have a look at [Async](https://github.com/caolan/async) instead of promises. Much more usable in recursive situations.

The only way I think you can do it with promises, would be to generate a `Promise` for each iteration and add them to a new array. You'd pass that new array to [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race). Something like:

```
Promise.race(val.map(function(item) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    // Determine result
    resolve(result);
  });
}))
  .then((result) => { /* Deal with result */ });
```